# React Recaptcha v3 Uncaught (in promise) null

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha-v3

I am trying to use react-recaptcha-v3 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-recaptcha-v3) and I exactly wrote the example :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ReCaptcha } from 'react-recaptcha-v3'
import { loadReCaptcha } from 'react-recaptcha-v3'

class ExampleComponent extends Component {

  verifyCallback = (recaptchaToken) => {
    // Here you will get the final recaptchaToken!!!  
    console.log(recaptchaToken, "<= your recaptcha token")
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    loadReCaptcha('site key (I can't give it here)')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <ReCaptcha
            sitekey="site key (I can't give it here)"
            action={console.log('action')}
            verifyCallback={this.verifyCallback}
        />

        <h2>Google ReCaptcha with React </h2>

        <code>
          1. Add <strong>your site key</strong> in the ReCaptcha component. <br/>
          2. Check <strong>console</strong> to see the token.
        </code>
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default ExampleComponent;
```

I wrote my domains names like this :

- localhost
- localhost:3000

And I got a site key and a secret key.

Here is what i get in console :

[image]

Comment: I am  having this exact problem. Were you ever able to resolve it? This isn't specific to `react-recaptcha-v3` - it happens when i just plain implement recaptcha 3 the way the docs instruct.

Comment: Sorry but I finally used react-recaptcha-v2....

Answer (score 0):

New answer :)

Firstly, I'm unsure if you said you added localhost & localhost:3000 to allowed domains. If you did you should remove them

> We advise to use a separate key for development and production and to not allow localhost on your production site key.

Even if you are using this for a test environment I wouldn't recommend it. Instead use the test site key & secret key. Localhost is enabled for test.

Next, I noticed your comment about using reCaptcha v2. If you are trying to implement reCaptcha the way v3 intends this won't work.

**reCaptcha v2**

Adds a script to a div that detects a users input checking if they a human.

**reCaptcha v3**

Adds an invisible div that detects wether it thinks the user is a bot or not. You have to setup a backend for it to work. It creates a score from 0.0 to 1.0. 0.0 meaning it is most likely a bot, 1.0 meaing it is most likely a human. It uses a token and then on your backend gives you a response that looks like this.

```
{
  "success": true|false,      // whether this request was a valid reCAPTCHA token for your site
  "score": number             // the score for this request (0.0 - 1.0)
  "action": string            // the action name for this request (important to verify)
  "challenge_ts": timestamp,  // timestamp of the challenge load (ISO format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ)
  "hostname": string,         // the hostname of the site where the reCAPTCHA was solved
  "error-codes": [...]        // optional
}
```

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

Next, I checked the documentation of the package.
You can't use `loadReCaptcha` in the same component, it must be in a Parent. Also `action={console.log('action')}` needs to be a string `action="action"` you configure this string in your google account.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#frontend_integration

Next, I won't recommend relying on a package as you make an uanessacry dependency.
I wrote an article here about it https://medium.com/@alexjamesdunlop/unnecessary-packages-b3623219d86.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script")
    script.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=_reCAPTCHA_site_key"
    script.addEventListener("load", () => {
      window.grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        window.grecaptcha.execute('_reCAPTCHA_site_key_', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
         // ...
        });
      });
    })
    document.body.appendChild(script)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
         className="g-recaptcha"
         data-sitekey="_Your_Key_"
         data-size="invisible"
      >
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

If you do want to continue using the package this is what it should look like.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { loadReCaptcha, ReCaptcha } from 'react-recaptcha-v3'

class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  verifyCallback = (token) => {
    // This is the token you send to your backend 
    console.log("token: ", token)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReCaptcha
          sitekey={your_site_key}
          // This must be a string and an example google gives is 'homepage' or 'login'
          action="action"
          verifyCallback={this.verifyCallback}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ParentComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    loadReCaptcha(your_site_key)
  }

  render() {
    return <ExampleComponent />
  }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Now if you did want to use v2 instead of v3 I show how to do that in the article
https://medium.com/@alexjamesdunlop/unnecessary-packages-b3623219d86

I recommend moving away from react Components and moving towards hooks, it's common practice to move away from it now, Components isn't supported.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html